# How to "get a new connection object, use it, close and dispose it each time you need", and handle the connection string?

Tags: .net, winforms, connection-string

As all we know, the connection string holds very important information...

So while taking this strategy while developing .NET Windows-based applications:

> get a new connection object, use it, close and dispose it each time you need

How can I handle the connection string within the application?

Comment: What? You follow the same approach: `using(Connection connection = new Connection(...){ ... }`. Can you elaborate on what you mean? It seems like you've answered your own question.

Comment: @silky, I mean, how to transfer connection string from GUI to  business layer and then data access layer in order to use it?

Comment: You should only need the connection in one place; you shouldn't be passing it around.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I would have a connection factory method centrally in the data layer. Everyone who needs a connection, should call that factory method; in order to ensure that all connections are created equal - and to avoid throwing magic strings around in the source code.

Example:

```
DBConnection conn = DBFactory.CreateConnection();
```

The only place you need to know about the connection string and where to get it, would be in that one method.

Comment: @driis, hhhm, ok you're right. But as you certainly know, this piece of code in in DAL, my question is: if we have got the connection string in GUI layer, how do we do trandfer it to the DAL? and more important, what about it if we take advantage of using block in c# for connection object?